# Copy generic stream without changing the positon

Tags: c#, .net, stream, copy, memorystream

I hava a `Stream` which constantly gets accessed from another thread.
But I want to access it for a brief moment for doing some gpu heavy paint work in a `UserControl`.

I currently use `Stream.CopyTo` method to copy it to a `MemoryStream` to proceed. But even the `Stream.CopyTo` method takes too long, and the work from the other thread is interrupted for a brief moment.

Heres my code:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
   if(myGenericStream != null) {
      using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
         int pos = myGenericStream.Position;

         myGenericStream.CopyTo(ms);

         myGenericStream.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin); //I have also tried myGenericStream.Position = pos

         ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
         // Paint work using the new MemoryStream...

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You cannot copy a stream without reading it first, so you cannot copy a stream without changing its position

Comment: Do you have control of the creation and consumption of the original stream? If so you can make your own stream implementation that wraps the original stream and caches the data from it for use in your paint method